# Can page size, synchronous or other pragma setting be changed in cordova-sqlite-storage / ionic-native/sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I would like to change the synchronous as NORMAL but when I tried to execute this

`PRAGMA synchronous = 1;`

It doesn't have an effect unlike when I execute

`PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;`